# Difference between calling method_missing in Ruby with and without parentheses

Tags: ruby, method-missing

Is there any possibility to establish in method_missing declaration in Ruby whether a given missing_method was called (without any arguments) using parentheses notation, ie:

```
foo.non_existing_method()
```

or using parentheses-less notation:

```
foo.non_existing_method
```

?

I need this to solve my very specific testing problem.

Answer (score 5):

No.

Since both are *exactly the same*, there cannot possibly be a way to detect the difference.

It doesn't make sense anyway, since both are *exactly the same*, so there cannot possibly any behavorial difference, either.

If you *could* detect the difference, then you could also have your method *behave* differently, which would be *extremely surprising* to any user of that method.

Comment: I suppose it's not a terribly surprising question, however, given the special case that `super` is different from `super()`.

Comment: @Phrogz: That's not a message send, though.

Comment: örgWMittag Right, but that this is the case is not obvious to end users, just as it's not obvious that `alias_method` is a method but `alias` is syntax, or that `&` may be implemented as a method but `&&` may not. My only point here is that there exists one case in the language where `xxx` behaves differently from `xxx()`, so it might not be _extremely_ surprising to some for a method to change its behavior based on invocation method.